# Should I descale my Saniflo macerator after neglecting to do so for many years?

Tags: plumbing

I've been in my home for 16 years and have a Saniflo toilet / shower combo in my basement. I have never descaled it and have never had any issues. Am I rolling the dice by not doing it or would it be too risky to do it after such a long period of time.

We do not use the toilet often, and the shower even less, if that matters.

Answer (score 1):

Yes use their descaler they recommend it for a reason. Life expectancy is 10 to 20 years. It is out of warranty by 14 years and close to end of service life. Take care of your poo squisher.

Answer (score 0):

It needs no service as long as you have no problems, and there's nothing you could do to break it when cleaning it (if you know what you're doing of course)

Comment: What qualifies as not "knowing what you're doing"? Your answer might be better with some preventative advice, and maybe a source for your statement about service.